# application.yml vs application.properties for Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration, format, yaml

In my project i'm currently using `application.yml` for configuration. Spring Initializr generate `application.properties`? What are the Pro/Cons for each one?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Well, they are just different data formats. Which one's nicer and easier to read? That's obviously subjective. [Here's](https://meetsnehal.wordpress.com/2015/09/12/yaml-an-alternative-to-properties-file-with-spring-boot/) a useful blog post.

As far as `spring-boot` configuration is concerned, note that there's only one documented shortcoming of using `YAML`. Per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings):

> YAML files can’t be loaded via the `@PropertySource` annotation. So in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

Comment: Is YAML configuration format widely accepted across the whole SpringBoot world? When we come to a 3rd party library that provides only properties format configuration, is it easy to convert it to yaml format ourselves?

Comment: @BruceSun It seems not so accepted, because official documentation uses it rarely, this uses .properties for instance: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html But my company's spring boot project template has yml...

Comment: They are not just different data formats. YAML supports utf-8, application.properties doesn't

Comment: Another question on this topic: When a library requires me to set a configuration to the application.yml file, can I assume that it can be loaded when I just set the property in the application.properties file? To be precise, is it the same mechanism to load a property for both files?

Comment: also, what happens when my code base provides both an `application.yaml` as well as `application.properties`? can I just move the stuff in, say, the `.yaml` one into `.properties` (changing format as required) and expect things to continue to work the same way?

Answer (score 54):

As per my knowledge, these are at least *some* of the differences:

1. `.properties` stores data in sequential format, whereas
   `.yml` stores data in hierarchical format.
2. `.properties` supports only key-value pairs (basically string values), whereas
   `.yml` supports key-value pair, as well as map, list & scalar type values.
3. `.properties` is specifically used by Java, whereas
   `.yml` can be used by other languages (eg Java, Python, ROR, etc).
4. When managing multiple configuration profiles, then:
   `.properties` requires you to create `.properties` file per every profile, whereas in
   `.yml` you can create a section for each specific profile inside a single `.yml` file.
5. In Spring projects, `@PropertySource` annotation can only be used with `.properties`.

Comment: Good answer, just remarks about **point#2**   `.properties file` : can supports key-value pair as well as map, list & scalar type values. + **point#3**  `.properties file` can be used with any language

Comment: so we can have either application.yml  or application.properties.. one is enough or both files required?

Comment: so we can have either application.yml  or application.properties.. one is enough or both files required?  if we keep both files , what is the impact , which one will be picked up

Comment: @Stunner It's completely depends on your requirements. But you can use both of them if they meet with your need. Example, I worked in one project and in that common properties like database configuration, cache configuration, mail configuration defined in application.properties and for device specific configuration we create different ymls.

Comment: so u mean to say ,  no matter how many properties file or yaml files declared  or even the combination of both properties file and yaml file,  the spring doesn't mind  the number and loads all of them and both of them?

Comment: No not exact that, Let's comes bit backward, Why properties or yml are used? Answer is for profiling and manage external properties. So not any professional developer create un-appropriate n number of files. In short have to create properties and yml file based on your number profile or some data which you want to pass as external data.

Comment: For second question, Spring not load all the profiles it load according to your need. Like active profile parameter or based on profile parameter you passed in environment variable or command line option.

Comment: I suppose you have bit confuse regarding properties or yml file define inside project and pass externally with command line param. Is it so? If you have some specific context then start chat or place question regarding that. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

One notable difference is how the properties are represented in each file. YAML files may use consistent spaces to denote hierarchy whereas properties file may use = to denote property values.

For ex.

Lists are represented hierarchically in YAML:

**headers:**

```
  - user-agent
  - x-wag-diagonalsize
```

Lists may be represented as inline list (separated by commas) in a properties file:

**headers = user-agent, x-wag-diagonalsize**

Another difference is we can add multiple configuration files into single yaml file.

For ex., we can add application.yaml(application specific properties) and bootstrap.yaml(server specific properties) into single config.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

**application.properties**

1. It uses a simple key-value pair format.
2. Properties are defined using the key=value syntax.
3. Properties can be written in a single line or multiple lines, but each property is represented by a single key-value pair.

   server.port=8080

   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
   spring.datasource.username=root
   spring.datasource.password=root

   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

**application.yml**

1. It uses a YAML (YAML Ain’t Markup Language) format.
2. Properties are defined using indentation and hierarchical structure.
3. Properties can be written in a more structured manner using indentation and nesting.
4. YAML supports lists and maps, making it easier to represent complex configurations.

   server:
   port: 8080

   spring:
   datasource:
   password: root
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
   username: root
   jpa:
   hibernate:
   ddl-auto: update
   properties:
   hibernate:
   show_sql: true

Reference: [spring boot properties vs. yaml](https://websparrow.org/spring/spring-boot-application-properties-vs-application-yml)