# @ConditionalOnProperty on a Bean, which must be loaded based on two conditions, coming from application.yml config file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm facing this kind of issue now, that I must give two conditions in one `@ConditionalOnProperty` which is class level.

I have a bean, say

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/blablabla")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.property.value1", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyBean{}
```

now there is a requirement that `MyBean` must be loaded based on two conditions, one is `my.property.value1.enabled:true` and the second is `my.property.value2:true` (both coming from application.yml file)

Now my question is there any way of doing this in one `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, if yes, so please paste here the working example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For simple boolean properties you could use `@ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty({"my.property.value1", "my.property.value2"})
```

**application.yml**:

```
my:
  property:
    value1: true
    value2: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do the following:

```java
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.property.value1.enabled} and ${my.property.value2}")
```

Comment: If it helped you and you fell like you can upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `@ConditionalProperty` name element can support an array:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.property", name = {"value1.enabled", "value2.enabled"}, havingValue = "true")
```

If the two properties are compared to different values, then you can leverage a Spring expression:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.property.value1.enabled} == true and ${my.property.value1.enabled} == true")
```

Comment: ok, does ConditionalOnExpression support conditions from application.yml file ? or only from .properties file?

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan Yes it does.

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462950/application-yml-vs-application-properties-for-spring-boot

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'

Comment: I am getting this kind of exception, in two cases

Comment: @ConditionalOnExpression("${my.property.value1.enabled} == true and ${my.property.value1.enabled} == true")

Comment: @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.property", name = {"value1.enabled", "value2.enabled"}, havingValue = "true")

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan What is the content of your yml config file?